# Using sed to get the text between two key words (but not the key words themselves)

Tags: bash, sed

So I have found this sed expression for getting the text between to keywords exclusive of the keywords:

```
cat example.txt | sed '/^KEYWORD1/,/^KEYWORD2/!d; //d'
```

where example.txt:

```
do
not
care
KEYWORD1
I
want
this
KEYWORD2
do
not
care
```

output:

```
I
want
this
```

However, I want to understand for sure what is going on with this expression.  My understanding is that with a 'pattern range' (correct me if this is improper terminology), that a bool is set when you hit the first match and that the command(s) following the pattern range are only executed if that bool is true.

Then there is the `//d` where the `//` is supposed to mean the last expression/regex that was matched.  So is it correct that in this case with a pattern range, the logic is as follows:

- loop
- Find `/^KEYWORD1/`, set bool to true, proceed with !d command which does not delete this line, then since the last regex was `/^KEYWORD1/` then `//d` is effectively `/^KEYWORD1/d` which deletes this line
- bool is true so it proceeds to not delete the 3 next lines and `/^KEYWORD1/` is not found on said lines so nothing is deleted
- Find `/^KEYWORD2/d`, execute !d and then `/^KEYWORD2/d` since this was the last regex used

So at this point I'm not sure how the lines before and after are not printed since it doesn't execute the commands (the `!d`) unless the pattern range flag is set to true.

Or does sed at least look at the command for every line and since the first command is an inverse delete, it somehow changes the logic to delete all other lines where the pattern range bool is false?

Any clarification on how this sed expression works will be appreciated.  I've read [this great resource](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) up and down  but still don't quite understand all the details of the expression.

Comment: If you hover your cursor over the `sed` flag above and choose `info` you can find a huge resource of sed related matter. Perhaps [this](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.3) link might also enlighten you.

Answer (score 1):

Your misunderstanding is this: `/address/!d` doesn't mean "if we match `address`, don't delete the line"; the `!` is the *negation* of the address, i.e., "if we *don't* match `address`, then *do delete* the line."

So the one-liner (better written without `cat`, by the way)

```
sed '/^KEYWORD1/,/^KEYWORD2/!d; //d' example.txt
```

does this:

- `/^KEYWORD1/,/^KEYWORD2/!d`: for all the lines outside the range `/^KEYWORD1/,/^KEYWORD2/`, i.e.,

  ```
  do
  not
  care
  do
  not
  care
  ```

  delete them. `d` jumps back to the start of the script. This leaves us with

  ```
  KEYWORD1
  I
  want
  this
  KEYWORD2
  ```

  where we don't want to print `KEYWORD1` and `KEYWORD2`.
- For these lines, we fall through to `//d`, which means "delete the last matching line".

  On the `KEYWORD1` line, we fall through and delete the line, because it was matched before. On the next three lines, we fall through, but there was no match, so we don't delete anything. On the `KEYWORD2` line, we fall through and delete because it was matched before – leaving us with the lines between the two patterns.

Comment: Thanks!  I wrote it with cat since I'm actually piping the output of another command into sed vs from a file, but point taken.

Comment: When you say 'd jumps back to the start of the script' do you mean it goes back to the start of what is left after the negation of the pattern range is deleted so that the second command (//d) can go through the remaining lines?

Comment: @jshort I meant it like this: sed processes the whole script for each line, and only a few commands change that standard flow. `d` is one: the current pattern space is discarded and not printed, the next line is loaded into the pattern space and we jump back to the first instruction. So "jumping back" was really meant for the current cycle, not jumping to another line.